# Transforming a data base into a new data frame to show the relationship between each row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame as seen below. How do I create a new data frame from what I have to show the nodes in each trail, then add 2 columns to indicate their trail number and colour?

I thought of using .iterrows() but I'm completely lost.

[image]

Comment: Post your code so that we can provide help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.rand(3,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = []
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for j in range(3):
        temp = row[j:j+2].to_list()
        out.append([temp[0], temp[1], i, colors[i]])
pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]